# PHP MYSQL fetching a TEXT with new lines

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

//after connecting etc..
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $string = "SELECT msg FROM $table WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($string)) or die(mysql_error());
    echo $result[msg];
?>
```

this is how the database is..

```
I wanted to install the database base.
I wanted to install the database server.
I wanted to install the Ubuntu.
```

when i retrieve them they appear as..

```
I wanted to install the database base.I wanted to install the database server.I wanted to install the Ubuntu.
```

Its a TEXT field.. is there a way to make them appear with the new lines? exactly the same?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try `echo "<pre>".$result[msg]."</pre>";` to check do newlines appear in code (or just take a look of output source). If does, convert newlines to `<br />` (`nl2br` function) and use it inside your html document.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this:

```
echo nl2br($result[msg]);
```

As long as browsers doesn't treat `\r\n` as real new-lines - you need to "convert" them to `<br>`'s with [nl2br()](http://php.net/nl2br)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) is what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use: 
`` REPLACE(`col_name`,"\n","<br />") as `col_name` `` 
You must use this after `SELECT`.

Example code:

`` SELECT *, REPLACE(`name`,"\n","<br />") as `name` FROM xyz WHERE id="%s" ``